# Correct way [sort of] creating custom Observables using RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I'm working on my custom `Observables` in an effort to make them more reusable throughout my code and wondering on the best [correct] way to do it.

What I am doing is just implementing the `Observable.OnSubscribe<>` interface and working at the `call()` method.

Basically, I want to subscribe to another `Observable` and depending on its result, emit one or other data conditionally. Is it a bad practice to subscribe to another `Observable` inside the aforementioned  `call()` method? It seems clumsy to me at least. Or should I use an Rx operator in a different way that I'm (still) not aware of?

**Note:** I'm not using Java8 and Retrolambda, so please, don't use lambdas on any possible answers.

Answer (score 3):

Creating custom Observables ranges from tricky to difficult and I wouldn't recommend it as the first step. Your scenario can be solved via `flatMap`:

```
source.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> call(Integer value) {
        if (value < 5) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
        return Observable.just(value * 2);
    }
});
```

> Is it a bad practice to subscribe to another Observable inside the aforementioned  call() method?

No, but you have to avoid what's called multiple onStart calls by wrapping the incoming `Subscriber` via `Subscribers.wrap()`.